# What does this code doing?

Tags: c#

I learn coding from the internet, and I try to understand this code I got from the internet. I copied a snippet from the code because I'm lost with it. Please help me.

```
private byte[] get(string request, IPAddress ipAddress, string community, string mibstring)
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 
      byte[] numArray1 = new byte[1024];
      int length1 = community.Length;
      string[] strArray = mibstring.Split('.');
      int length2 = strArray.Length;
      int index1 = 0;
      int num1 = length2;
      int num2 = 0;
      for (int index2 = 0; index2 < num1; ++index2)
      {
        int num3 = (int) Convert.ToInt16(strArray[index2]);
        if (num3 > (int) sbyte.MaxValue)
        {
          numArray1[index1] = Convert.ToByte(128 + num3 / 128);
          numArray1[index1 + 1] = Convert.ToByte(num3 - num3 / 128 * 128);
          index1 += 2;
          ++length2;
        }
        else
        {
          numArray1[index1] = Convert.ToByte(num3);
          ++index1;
        }
      }
      int size = 29 + length1 + length2 - 1;
      byte[] numArray2 = buffer;
```

I have trouble with this buffer thing. If I'm not wrong this buffer is an array with 1024 0 elements.

Than what does this code do?:

```
  byte[] numArray2 = buffer;
```

There is no index just the name. Copy the whole array?

```
  byte[] numArray2 = buffer;
  int index3 = num2;
  int num4 = 1;
  int num5 = index3 + num4;
  int num6 = 48;
  numArray2[index3] = (byte) num6;
  byte[] numArray3 = buffer;
  int index4 = num5;
  int num7 = 1;
  int num8 = index4 + num7;
  int num9 = (int) Convert.ToByte(size - 2);
  numArray3[index4] = (byte) num9;
  byte[] numArray4 = buffer;
  int index5 = num8;
  int num10 = 1;
  int num11 = index5 + num10;
  int num12 = 2;
  numArray4[index5] = (byte) num12;
  byte[] numArray5 = buffer;
  int index6 = num11;
  int num13 = 1;
  int num14 = index6 + num13;
  int num15 = 1;
  numArray5[index6] = (byte) num15;
  byte[] numArray6 = buffer;
  int index7 = num14;
  int num16 = 1;
  int num17 = index7 + num16;
  int num18 = 0;
  numArray6[index7] = (byte) num18;
  byte[] numArray7 = buffer;
  int index8 = num17;
  int num19 = 1;
  int num20 = index8 + num19;
  int num21 = 4;
  numArray7[index8] = (byte) num21;
  byte[] numArray8 = buffer;
  int index9 = num20;
  int num22 = 1;
  int num23 = index9 + num22;
  int num24 = (int) Convert.ToByte(length1);
  numArray8[index9] = (byte) num24;
  foreach (byte @byte in Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(community))
    buffer[num23++] = @byte;
  int num25;
  if (request == "get")
  {
    byte[] numArray9 = buffer;
    int index2 = num23;
    int num3 = 1;
    num25 = index2 + num3;
    int num26 = 160;
    numArray9[index2] = (byte) num26;
  }
  else
  {
    byte[] numArray9 = buffer;
    int index2 = num23;
    int num3 = 1;
    num25 = index2 + num3;
    int num26 = 161;
    numArray9[index2] = (byte) num26;
  }
  byte[] numArray10 = buffer;
  int index10 = num25;
  int num27 = 1;
  int num28 = index10 + num27;
  int num29 = (int) Convert.ToByte(20 + length2 - 1);
  numArray10[index10] = (byte) num29;
  byte[] numArray11 = buffer;
  int index11 = num28;
  int num30 = 1;
  int num31 = index11 + num30;
  int num32 = 2;
  numArray11[index11] = (byte) num32;
  byte[] numArray12 = buffer;
  int index12 = num31;
  int num33 = 1;
  int num34 = index12 + num33;
  int num35 = 4;
  numArray12[index12] = (byte) num35;
  byte[] numArray13 = buffer;
  int index13 = num34;
  int num36 = 1;
  int num37 = index13 + num36;
  int num38 = 0;
  numArray13[index13] = (byte) num38;
  byte[] numArray14 = buffer;
  int index14 = num37;
  int num39 = 1;
  int num40 = index14 + num39;
  int num41 = 0;
  numArray14[index14] = (byte) num41;
  byte[] numArray15 = buffer;
  int index15 = num40;
  int num42 = 1;
  int num43 = index15 + num42;
  int num44 = 0;
  numArray15[index15] = (byte) num44;
  byte[] numArray16 = buffer;
  int index16 = num43;
  int num45 = 1;
  int num46 = index16 + num45;
  int num47 = 1;
  numArray16[index16] = (byte) num47;
  byte[] numArray17 = buffer;
  int index17 = num46;
  int num48 = 1;
  int num49 = index17 + num48;
  int num50 = 2;
  numArray17[index17] = (byte) num50;
  byte[] numArray18 = buffer;
  int index18 = num49;
  int num51 = 1;
  int num52 = index18 + num51;
  int num53 = 1;
  numArray18[index18] = (byte) num53;
  byte[] numArray19 = buffer;
  int index19 = num52;
  int num54 = 1;
  int num55 = index19 + num54;
  int num56 = 0;
  numArray19[index19] = (byte) num56;
  byte[] numArray20 = buffer;
  int index20 = num55;
  int num57 = 1;
  int num58 = index20 + num57;
  int num59 = 2;
  numArray20[index20] = (byte) num59;
  byte[] numArray21 = buffer;
  int index21 = num58;
  int num60 = 1;
  int num61 = index21 + num60;
  int num62 = 1;
  numArray21[index21] = (byte) num62;
  byte[] numArray22 = buffer;
  int index22 = num61;
  int num63 = 1;
  int num64 = index22 + num63;
  int num65 = 0;
  numArray22[index22] = (byte) num65;
  byte[] numArray23 = buffer;
  int index23 = num64;
  int num66 = 1;
  int num67 = index23 + num66;
  int num68 = 48;
  numArray23[index23] = (byte) num68;
  byte[] numArray24 = buffer;
  int index24 = num67;
  int num69 = 1;
  int num70 = index24 + num69;
  int num71 = (int) Convert.ToByte(6 + length2 - 1);
  numArray24[index24] = (byte) num71;
  byte[] numArray25 = buffer;
  int index25 = num70;
  int num72 = 1;
  int num73 = index25 + num72;
  int num74 = 48;
  numArray25[index25] = (byte) num74;
  byte[] numArray26 = buffer;
  int index26 = num73;
  int num75 = 1;
  int num76 = index26 + num75;
  int num77 = (int) Convert.ToByte(6 + length2 - 1 - 2);
  numArray26[index26] = (byte) num77;
  byte[] numArray27 = buffer;
  int index27 = num76;
  int num78 = 1;
  int num79 = index27 + num78;
  int num80 = 6;
  numArray27[index27] = (byte) num80;
  byte[] numArray28 = buffer;
  int index28 = num79;
  int num81 = 1;
  int num82 = index28 + num81;
  int num83 = (int) Convert.ToByte(length2 - 1);
  numArray28[index28] = (byte) num83;
  byte[] numArray29 = buffer;
  int index29 = num82;
  int num84 = 1;
  int num85 = index29 + num84;
  int num86 = 43;
  numArray29[index29] = (byte) num86;
  for (int index2 = 2; index2 < length2; ++index2)
    buffer[num85++] = Convert.ToByte(numArray1[index2]);
  byte[] numArray30 = buffer;
  int index30 = num85;
  int num87 = 1;
  int num88 = index30 + num87;
  int num89 = 5;
  numArray30[index30] = (byte) num89;
  byte[] numArray31 = buffer;
  int index31 = num88;
  int num90 = 1;
  int num91 = index31 + num90;
  int num92 = 0;
  numArray31[index31] = (byte) num92;
  Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
  socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 3500);
  IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 161);
  EndPoint remoteEP = (EndPoint) ipEndPoint;
  socket.SendTo(buffer, size, SocketFlags.None, (EndPoint) ipEndPoint);
  try
  {
    socket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref remoteEP);
  }
  catch (SocketException ex)
  {
    buffer[0] = byte.MaxValue;
  }
  return buffer;
}
```

i completely lost in this code. This code get the network printers counter one by one. And i dont know how it does.

here is the calling of the method:

```
byte[] numArray2 = this.get("get", machineIPAddress, "public",    "1.3.6.1.2.1.43.10.2.1.4.1.1");
```

Comment: `Copy the whole array?` yes! You guessed it!

Comment: @Sweeper: does it copy it or does it make another reference to it?

Comment: but whats the point of it? why he not declare a new one? or use the buffer array?

Comment: The best way to learn is to run the code and see what it does. Testing is a good tool.

Comment: It actually makes another reference to it. What's the point? I don't know! Show me some more code!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.write7bitencodedint(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sweeper i copied the whole code. Danny i know what this code do but dont know how! I want to understand it and use it.

Comment: @Guba: Step through it with a debugger and look at what each line does. If there is any particular line that you don't understand then ask about that one specifically. Also the names make it look like decompiled code which means it might not actually be code that anybody wrote so the original source may well make more sense if you can get that.

Comment: Okay chris. How can i a check with line by line with debugger, i only can use the debugger to compile my code ans search for errors warnings. How can i change that?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down this line:

```
byte[] numArray2 = buffer;
```

1. It creates a space in memory for a **reference**
2. It declares that the reference will be to an object of type `byte[]`
3. It attaches the name `numArray2` to that reference
4. Finally, it copies the value of reference `buffer` to reference `numArray2`. *Both variables now point to the same object.*